# What happens with my collection when I refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, meteor, collections

I'm new to Meteor and I just want to inspect the content of my collection via console.log

Therefore I used this code:

```
var TestCollection = new Mongo.Collection('testcollection');
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    console.log("Client ");
    console.log(TestCollection.find().fetch());

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    console.log("Server");
    console.log(TestCollection.find().count());
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    if(TestCollection.find().count() ===0){
        TestCollection.insert({test: 'testvalue'}); 
    }
  });
}
```

When the servers starts

```
console.log(TestCollection.find().fetch());
```

Gives me the content of my collection, however when I hit the refresh button, the collection appears to be empty. So what happens to my collection when I hit the refresh button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the auto-publish package, this is just a timing issue, and the client has not yet received the data.

Try changing your client code to this:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  console.log('On startup');
  console.log(TestCollection.find().fetch());

  Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('After 50ms');
    console.log(TestCollection.find().fetch());
  }, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "var" keyword when you define the collection.

I think using the "var" keyword makes it a locally scoped variable, keeping your server & client side collections separate.